# Get max length for title and prompt for an ip phone?

Tags: java, cisco, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

i am developing a JTapi application that will work on all models of ip phones, and i display title and prompt dynamically, and i was wondering how to get max length for title and prompt for an ip phone model.

Answer (score 0):

The specifications can be found in the CiscoIPPhone.xsd (Cisco Unified IP Phone Services
XML Schema File) i.e [XML Schema 7.1.3](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/all_models/xsi/7_1_3/xmlschema.html#wp1022188)